# Как подключить БД на heroku.com?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, heroku

Мне нужно подключить базу данных(postgres или любую другую) на heroku.com

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: добавьте конкретики

Comment: с вопросом я не знаком. там что, нет `документации`?

Comment: @finally Ага, тут можно в двух смыслах понять. Всмысле чтоб дб крутилась на heroku или чтоб с heroku обратиться к дб?

Comment: @Victor VosMottor, чтобы крутилось на heroku.com бд. и там её же создать. как это правильно сделать?

Comment: https://www.heroku.com/postgres